# Dynamodb get_item and put_item without data types in python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I currently have a python script that looks like:

```
import boto3
...
response = dynamodb.get_item(
  TableName = dynamodb_table_name,
  Key = {
    "snippet_id": {
      "S": snippet_id
    }
  }
)
if "Item" in response:
    item = response["Item"]
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

This prints something akin to:

```
{
    "var_1": {
        "BOOL": false
    }, 
    "var_2": {
        "S": "Text"
    }, 
    "snippet_id": {
        "S": "3a97e45c-ffed-4c76-8bb4-b2a32f49a5d2"
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do the type detection and return:

```
{
    "var_1": False, 
    "var_2": "Text",
    "snippet_id": "3a97e45c-ffed-4c76-8bb4-b2a32f49a5d2"
}
```

Also, can this be done for the query as well?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use the put_item? Looks like you are adding the types yourself.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it has to do with the fact that I'm using 'client' objects instead of 'resource' objects. Resources are a more abstract version that helps to take care of the object types.

Answer (score 10):

#### TLDR

Use `resource` instead of `client`.

#### Summary

In essence, you can call `boto3.client()` or `boto3.resource()`.

**Client** returns **dynamoDB syntax**, which looks like this:

```py
'var_1' : {'S':"string"}
```

**Resource** returns **normal syntax**, which looks like this:

```py
'var_1' : "string"
```

#### Further Reading

At its core, all that Boto3 does is call AWS APIs on your behalf. For the majority of the AWS services, Boto3 offers two distinct ways of accessing these abstracted APIs:

- **Client**: low-level service access
- **Resource**: higher-level object-oriented service access
- **Reference**: https://realpython.com/lessons/clients-and-resources/

Comment: I tried using boto3.resource(), still it returns along with datatypes. What could be the issue?